# The logic of ( number | 0 ) statement gives an integer in javascript

Tags: javascript, logic

Converting floating number into integer We can use `( number | 0 )` statement instead of `parseInt(number)` in Javascript. for example : `( 3.343 | 0)` gives an integer value `3`.
 Please Explain  what is the logic behind `( number | 0 )` statement.

Comment: I'ts a way in javascript of making a number into a integer.  The Javascript Engine can then do certain optmizations,.. eg. Integer muliply / add etc, instead of double.

Comment: Are you asking how `number | 0` works or why `number | 0` is used rather than `parseInt`?

Comment: No, you should not use this instead of a proper `parseInt`.

Answer (score 1):

The `|` operator performs bitwise logical `OR`. It requires its parameters to be integers, so it will convert a string to an integer. So

```
( number | 0 )
```

is equivalent to:

```
( parseInt(number, 10) | 0 )
```

Any number or'ed with `0` will return that same number, so that makes it equivalen to:

```
parseInt(number, 10)
```

Comment: I think there might be some confusion from the OP about type coercion here too. In the case described above, the confusion is how `"123" | 0 = 123`.

Comment: No, those are not equivalent. Try with the input `number = "0xFF"`. Or `1e11`. Or `0b11`. Or `Infinity`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the single pipe between the number and 0 is bitwise operator that treat their operands as a sequence of 32 bits (zeroes and ones).
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.7c_%28Bitwise_OR%29